# serialize int to vector of bytes using std::vector::reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++

Next function works fine:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> serialize_bytes(uint32_t ui)
{
    return {(uint8_t*)&ui, (uint8_t*)(&ui+1)};
}
```

But its result depends on endianess of machine.

I also need to serialize bytes in reverse order:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> serialize_bytes(uint32_t ui)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t>::reverse_iterator 
        begin{(uint8_t*)(&ui+1)-1}
      , end{(uint8_t*)(&ui)-1};  //ERROR: Calling a private constructor
    return {begin, end};
}
```

I know multiple other ways to do serialization. The interest of this Q is to construct reverse_iterator from pointer in manner like first snippet does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<uint8_t>::reverse_iterator` can only point to elements of a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Use `std::reverse_iterator<uint8_t *>`:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> serialize_bytes(uint32_t ui)
{
    using iter_t = std::reverse_iterator<std::uint8_t *>;
    std::uint8_t *ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t *>(&ui);
    return {iter_t(ptr + sizeof ui), iter_t(ptr)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to help you with your task.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> serialize_bytes(uint32_t ui)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> v{(uint8_t*)&ui, (uint8_t*)(&ui+1)};
    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    return v;
}
```

Comment: But this does redundant operations.

Answer (score 0):

I took the above idea and rewrite it in own manner

```
std::vector<uint8_t> serialize_bytes(uint32_t ui)
{
    std::reverse_iterator<uint8_t*> begin{(uint8_t*)(&ui+1)}, end{(uint8_t*)(&ui)};
    return {begin, end};
}
```

thank you @HolyBlackCat

Comment: You should probably accept the answer that inspired your final solution. In the end, it was the one that answered the question.